# Static IP - Load Balancer - Storage Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use a gcloud load balancer to serve different storage buckets.

Example:

http://{static ip}/ (default bucket)

http://{static ip}/bucket1

I have reserved a static IP & setup a firewall rule, but when it comes to serving the bucket contents, I'm getting a permissions error.

Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Service account to list or get the objects,
 it needs to have storage.objectReader role to it. For a reference of which IAM permissions are contained in each IAM role, see [Cloud Storage IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).

Are you looking something similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing)? Once you have set up [content based load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example) you can add a storage bucket to it.